# Square brackets in XML Element Name

Tags: html, xml, encoding

Is it possible to use square brackets in an XML element's name?

for instance:

```
<root>
    <Data.Entity.Result[0]>Hello</Data.Entity.Result[0]>
</root>
```

I tried using escape characters like...

```
    &lsqb; 
    &lbrack;
    &#91;
```

...and so forth, but I still get validation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use square brackets (or entity references) in element names.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn (especially the "Names and Tokens" section).

Comment: On the other hand, there are many other (non-Ascii) brackets that *can* be used. So I think the crucial question is why one would want to use such characters in XML element names—this is relevant in considering what alternatives might quality.